# If field = a echo... else

Tags: php, if-statement

On a report, I'm trying to show a signature depending on the value of a field.
So, I'm adding php inside html.

```
<?php

if ($lawyer == "DS") {
    echo '<div class="signature">
<p class="boldcentrado">
E.D.</br>
Lawyer</p></div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
<p class="boldcentrado">DS</p>
</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="signature">
<p class="boldcentrado">
E.D.</br>
Lawyer</p></div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
<p class="boldcentrado">PM</p>
</div>';
}
?>
```

If field "lawyer" equals "DS", it should "show":

```
<div class="signature">
<p class="boldcentrado">
E.D.</br>
Lawyer</div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
<p class="boldcentrado">DS</p>
</div>
```

if it's any other value, show:

```
<div class="signature">
<p class="boldcentrado">
E.D.</br>
Lawyer</div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
<p class="boldcentrado">PM</p>
</div>
```

Problem is it's always showing the first option, no matter the field value.

Comment: Can you `echo($lawyer); exit;`  what is in $lawyer??

Comment: There is a missing `</p>`

Comment: -> lawyer is the name of the field which can have two values: DS or PMM. On html there is another "lawyer" but that's just a string of text that says the job of the person

Comment: Yes, your, right, dallonsi, my bad! But on the project it's not missing :) I've edited here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. tested and changing the $lawyer is doing exactly what it is suppose to.

You code looks horrible. Split HTML as much possible from your PHP

```
<?php

$lawyer = 'S';

if ($lawyer == "DS") : ?>
<div class="signature">
    <p class="boldcentrado">
        E.D.</br>
        Lawyer</p>
</div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
    <p class="boldcentrado">DS</p>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="signature">
    <p class="boldcentrado">
        E.D.</br>
        Lawyer</p>
</div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
    <p class="boldcentrado">PM</p>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Change the value of lawyer is throwing out expected, so the value of lawyer that you apply is always "DS"

Comment: Thank you for testing and for the help on the "styling". So now I know it's somewhere else the conflict :)

Comment: @Whoopcg - I didn't really help, but the styling will be less of a headache for you this way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the case sensitivity of the match in the if statement.
I took your code and created a small test script to show you it's behavior ( I did make a function of your code, for ease of invocation )

```
<?php

function show($lawyer) {

    if ($lawyer == "DS") {
        echo '<div class="signature">
    <p class="boldcentrado">
    E.D.</br>
    Lawyer</div>
    <div class="assinaturacaixa">
    <p class="boldcentrado">DS</p>
    </div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="signature">
    <p class="boldcentrado">
    E.D.</br>
    Lawyer</div>
    <div class="assinaturacaixa">
    <p class="boldcentrado">PM</p>
    </div>';
    }
}

// This shows the DS 
echo "Lawyer is DS -- Should show DS:";
show("DS");


// these show PM
echo "lawyer = NOPE:";
show("NOPE");

echo "lawyer = NP:";
show("NP");

echo "lawyer = <empty>:";
show("");

// And due to case sensitivity this wont show DS either
echo "lawyer = ds <-- lower case:";
show("ds");
```

There is one more thing I'd like to let you know. If it's only that single field that needs to be changed, it might be better to refactor the page to something like:

```
<div class="signature">
    <p class="boldcentrado">
    E.D.</br>
    Lawyer</p>
</div>
<div class="assinaturacaixa">
    <p class="boldcentrado"><?=getExpectedFieldValue(...)?></p>
</div>
```

and let that function return DS or PM accordingly.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you're suggesting that maybe the field is saying, for example, "ds" and for that mismatch in case sensitivity, the code is not working. Well... I only have two options for users to choose from, they don't have to write the names... so I see "DS" in the field... :\ But if it's working for you, may be a conflict with something else? And thank you for your help